# Wiring/ArrowLooping every element in a list with every other element in the list

Tags: haskell, arrows, netwire

I asked a question about this earlier but I don't think I really knew what I was asking.  I think I understand my problem slightly better now.

I'm using netwire, an arrowized FRP library, and having some trouble getting this arrowloop implemented.

I have

```
f :: ArrowLoop r =>  a  -> r [a]  a
g :: ArrowLoop r => [a] -> r ()  [a]
```

Such that `g` basically ties every element in the given list with the list of every other element using `f`...um...this is hard to really say using words so I'll give an example with a list of length 4:

```
g [x0, x1, x2, x3] = proc _ -> do
  rec
     y0 <- f x0 -< [y1, y2, y3]
     y1 <- f x1 -< [y0, y2, y3]
     y2 <- f x2 -< [y0, y1, y3]
     y3 <- f x3 -< [y0, y1, y2]
  returnA -< [y0, y1, y2, y3]
```

(I have a helper function `selects :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]`, that turns something like `[x,y,z]` into `[(x, [y,z]), (y, [x,z]), (x, [x,y])]`)

Now...I've compiled this hard-coded version and this already works and delivers exactly the results that I wanted mostly.  It runs without any funky <> issues.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this "exact" thing...but with a general number of list elements?

---

For reference, my implementation of `selects` comes from Simon Marlow,

```
selects :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
selects = go []
  where
    go xs [] = []
    go xs (y:ys) = (y,xs++ys) : go (y:xs) ys
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't test this properly since I didn't have any example `f` to run it against but I believe this generalizes the arrow pattern you have:

```
g :: ArrowLoop r => [a] -> r () [a]
g = listLoop . map f

listLoop :: ArrowLoop r => [r [a] a] -> r () [a]
listLoop l = const [] ^>> go l where
    go []     = arr (const [])
    go (r:rs) = proc bs -> do
        rec a  <- r     -< bs ++ as
            as <- go rs -< bs ++ [a]
        returnA -< a : as
```

So first we map with `f` to get the list of arrows `[f x0, f x1, ...]` and then we feed it to a combinator I named `listLoop` which takes a list of arrows and defines a recursive arrow which essentially has the same logic as your `selects`. `bs` is the list of results from arrows preceding `r` (analogous to `xs` in `selects`) and `as` are the results from the arrows following `r`. For each `r` we feed in the results of the other arrows but not the result of `r` itself (which is `a`). Then we recurse, appending `a` to the list of preceding results.

Comment: This compiles; I'm sorry that I can't really say anything though because it ends up working for some reason (I get a lot of NaN's in my calculation).  If you are willing, I can get some simple netwire wires and maybe you could go from there to see why it doesn't work?  I appreciate your help however.

Comment: Yeah, if you can include some example wire that works with your hardcoded `g` and some simple, runnable `main` I'd be happy to debug it further.